# Append dictionary values to dataframe if values are missing using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to append rows if this value is missing from a specific column.

**Data**

```
ID  Date    type    energy
AA  Q1 2022 a       1
AA  Q2 2022 ok      1
AA  Q3 2022 yes     1
AA  Q4 2022 yes     4
FC  Q1 2022 no      4
FC  Q2 2022 no      4
FC  Q3 2022 yes     45
FC  Q4 2022 yes     5
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date    type    energy
AA  Q1 2022 a       1
AA  Q2 2022 ok      1
AA  Q3 2022 yes     1
AA  Q4 2022 yes     4
FC  Q1 2022 no      4
FC  Q2 2022 no      4
FC  Q3 2022 yes     45
FC  Q4 2022 yes     5
BC  Q1 2022         0
DA  Q1 2022         0
```

**Doing**

```
#values =   {'BC': 'Q1 2022', 'DA': 'Q1 2022}
#df1 = df.merge(df, how='left').fillna({'energy': 0})
```

However, this is not appending, not sure how to attach the values dictionary within this script. I am still researching, any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do

```
apdf = pd.Series(values).reset_index()
apdf.columns = df.columns[:2]
df = pd.concat([df, apdf]).fillna({'energy': 0})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a dict-comprehension and `append`. In a one-liner:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'ID':[x for x in values],
                        'Date':[values[x] for x in values]}))
```

Comment: `append`? deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

```
values = {'BC': 'Q1 2022', 'DA': 'Q1 2022'}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": values.values(),
    "type": "",
    "energy": 0,
    }, index=values.keys())])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python expects a list for the values of the dictionary rather than values.
Then, use [`append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'BC': ['Q1 2022'], 'DA': ['Q1 2022']})
df = df.append(df1)

# replace to satisfy the desired output
df['energy'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['type'].fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Not a fan of manually inputting the data for the DataFrame function

Comment: agreed but I think this answer makes it clear how to go about creating a df from a dict which I think might be where the OP was stuck